# Delphi, API call with RestDebugger, error for add new data

Tags: api, rest, delphi, post, content-type

I want to make an API call with RestDebugger. With postMan, I managed to get a result. The API allows you to retrieve a list of data and write a new record. With RestDebugger, reading works with the GET method. There is an error message with the POST method.

ODATA_PROVIDER_ERROR an internal server error occured. details code : UNSUPPORTED_CONTENT_TYPE, The content type multipart form-data boudary= = Embt boudary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0FCt.png)

I think I have correctly defined the content type but it is not taken into account. Yet the same call works with the GET. How to impose the content type with this Delphi tool?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After defining the parameters with Delphi 11's RESTDebugger, after saying "Copy Components", right click and paste on the form and add the components. Then open the properties section of the RESTRequest component to the Params section. You will see that the ConnectTypeStr section is empty for all the parameters you add from here. Select all parameters and enter "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in this field, then right click on RESTRequest and choose Execute. You will see the data successfully.

In possible versions after Delphi 10.3, if you are entering the parameters manually and you want to upgrade, you will definitely need to add this line.